# Manipulating section of arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, resize

I have a matrix of **W** of large row and column dimension. Each of the row  represents feature values(filled with double value).And the matrix is constructed as:

```
  Hashmap<Integer,Arraylist<Double>> W = new Hashmap<Integer,Arraylist<Double>>();
```

While making computation, I need to take certain portion of each of the rows and update them in matrix. I looked for `subList` method in `Arraylist`. But the problem is it returns only list but I am in need of arraylist. Because many of the methods that I have already implemented take `<Arraylist>` as argument. So what can be the solution for this case?

Example

```
 w1 = [1,3 ,4,6,9,1,34,5,21,5,2,5,1]
 w11 = [1,3,4]
 w11 = w11 +1 = [2,4,5]
 This changes w1 to = [2,4 ,5,6,9,1,34,5,21,5,2,5,1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I looked for subList method in Arraylist.But the problem is it returns only list but i am in need of arraylist

That is not a problem at all. In fact, you should change your code to use `List` wherever possible.

A `List` is an interface which concrete types such as the `ArrayList` implement. The below is perfectly valid:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
list.add("world");
```

I recommend changing your `W` to this:

```
Hashmap<Integer, List<Double>> W = new Hashmap<Integer, List<Double>>();
```

Comment: +1. Indeed, unless some functionality of `ArrayList` is explicitly required, it's always recommended to go with the generic class as parameter.

Comment: Actually i have make use of **Arraylist** in most of the palce. changing will be like starting from scratch.:(

Comment: You can always do `new ArrayList(list)` or you can even type cast it but I don't recommend such practices.

Comment: @thetna: Changing it is worth the effort, although many IDEs can make these changes for you automatically.  For example, if you open up the `ArrayList` class in Eclipse, you can use Refactor/Use Supertype Where Possible to automatically replace most occurrences of `ArrayList` with `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `ArrayList` to provide a view of a slice of another `ArrayList`.  Like this:

```
class ArrayListSlice<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
  private ArrayList<E> backing_list;
  private int start_idx;
  private int len;
  ArrayListSlice(ArrayList<E> backing_list, int start_idx, int len) {
    this.backing_list = backing_list;
    this.start_idx = start_idx;
    this.len = len;
  }
  public E get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || idx >= len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return backing_list.get(start_idx + index);
  }
  ... set, others? ...
}
```

Then you can do `w11 = new ArrayListSlice<Double>(w1, 0, 3)`.  Any operations on `w11` will appear in `w1`, assuming you implement `set` correctly.

You will probably need to implement most the methods of ArrayList to make this work.  Some may work if they just rely on others, but that's hard to tell from the spec.